# How can I compile C++ code with GCC compiler?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

I wrote C++ code in notepad and want to compile with GCC compiler. Is GCC compiler a program? from which site I can download it? I don't have any information about it. What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start by downloading Code::Blocks, its an cross-platform IDE that can be downloaded including MinGW GCC compiler.

http://www.codeblocks.org/

But if You're using Linux you can use just a "gcc" command in the terminal.

Comment: Code::Blocks is probably the best option here. It's almost certainly Windows if the code was created with Notepad.

Comment: g++ is the C++ compiler. gcc will complain if asked to compile C++ code.

Answer (score 3):

GCC is a program. if you have linux its probably installed. to chek just type in the console line gcc. if you get a out put with the syntax - it's installed else - type the command that's suggested. in order to compile something type:

```
gcc <file name>
```

it will create a .out file that you could run from the console line.
for more info type:

```
man gcc
```

Comment: At least for Fedora (and probably for other distributions too), unless you ask to install a development station compilers and such won't be installed. They are available, just not installed by default. Check your distribution's documentation on how to install C++ development tools. Also, today there are at least two options, g++ and clang (LLVM C++ compiler).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use C-free 5.0 which is small and can use many compilers. Small ide. You just need to make it automatically choose the library and inclue paths.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows you can try one of ports: [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/).

If you're on Linux, you probably have it installed (try gcc --version) or at least available from repository (check your distributions "installer").

There is also a number of (free) IDEs that you can also get and use them instead of notepad. Google for Eclipse/CDT, Netbeans, code::blocks, etc.