# How can I Compile Fortran Codes?

Tags: fortran

I wrote Fortran Codes and I want to compile them. Sorry I don't know more information about this question because It is one of my friends question. Is there a specific program for Compiling Fortran Codes?

Comment: You can't tell us more? Really? Where did you get a fortran compiler? Why are you writing fortran if you don't have a compiler? Voting to close as not a real question.

Comment: If I had any compiler I wouldn't ask this question. I wanna to compile Fortran codes. It is a real question. Please be more optimistic. Thanks

Comment: I had also compile fortran code on `Code :Blocks` IDE after managing compiler setting but now I had forgot the compiler setting...

Comment: The program you need is a Fortran compiler. There are many.  Perhaps gfortran.

Comment: Compiling Fortran code should not be much different than compiling C++ code, which you asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841161/how-can-i-compile-c-code-with-gcc-compiler)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compile a fortran program by typing a line similar to the following:

```
f77 -o myprogram myprogram.f
```

It is important that you understand what is happening here:

`f77` is the name of the `Fortran compiler`. Your compiler may have a different name such as `g77, ifc. or pgf77`.
The `-o` option tells the compiler that the next word (here, myprogram) will be the name of the binary version of the program. If you omit this option, most systems will use the default name `a.out` for the binary version regardless of the name of your program. It's OK to use this default, though it's usually helpful to use a more meaningful name. The binary file is often called the executable file because the computer can run (execute) it.
myprogram.f is the name of the file that contains the source code of your program. The source code is the file of instructions that you actually edit and type. Your source file could be named something other than myprogram.f, such as homework1.f. or some other descriptive name. On many systems the name of the source file must end with the `suffix .f` or the compiler is apt to become unhappy.
To run the program, simply type the name of the executable file:

```
myprogram
```

You can find more about it [Here](http://www.fortran.gantep.edu.tr/compiling-g95-basic-guide.html) also

Comment: Or f90 or gfortran or ifort or ....  Let's hope not f77 since FORTRAN 77 has been obsolete for about 20 years from Fortran 90.   Fortran 95 compilers are widely available and most have features of Fortran 2003.